# django: call overridden model method from django template

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have overrode *(overrided?)* the `get_FOO_display()` method of django model class (see: doc [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)) to return some different choice field mapping. But, on calling this function from the django template as `{{ model_object.get_FOO_display }}` calls the base class method instead of the new overridden method.

I read the source code [django/db/models/base.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L969) and it seems like this is not some regular method rather, it is created dynamically for the model fields. *(let me know if am getting it wrong)*

Is there a way I can resolve to the overridden method from the template ?

See this code to get the essence of my issue:

```
class UserStatus(models.Model):
    invite_status = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=USER_STATUS, default='new')

    # Overridden method
    def get_invite_status_display(self):
        return dict(USER_STATUS_DISPLAY).get(self.invite_status)
```

Yes, I need to display different content than the `choices` dict and no, I cannot keep my to-be-displayed content in the choice dict in the first place.

Let me know if there is any possible way to make this template call work.

Thanks.

Comment: Would have edited it, but you seem lost on this one, so I comment instead: "I have overridden", or "I overrode". Hard one, I must say.

Comment: Can you explain why you needed to override this method specifically, rather than just creating a new one? Also, is that the actual indentation?

Comment: I'm still not sure where you'd  actually be able to override this, but the magic happens [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2f9861d823620da7ecb291a8f005f53da12b1e89/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L704)

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, my same thoughts exactly. I am working on someone else's code and maybe the developer thought that overriding this would work something like overriding for eg: `__unicode__`. I am just fascinated by its behaviour and wanted to know more. I plan to resort to a new method if I don't find any way. Thanks for your help and so sorry for the indentation; I've fixed that.

Comment: @Sayse Thanks for pointing that out. Yes, my initial thought to override `contribute_to_class` method but that would be unpleasant to see. As, replied to Daniel I was fascinated by its behaviour and maybe I'll now go back to create a new method. Thanks.

Comment: Note, assuming you just need the original choices to display in an editing form, another way to approach this might simply be to override the field with those choices in a custom form, and leave the underlying model field with the display choices.

Comment: where and how is USER_STATUS defined?