# Django: can't override get_FOO_display()

Tags: django, django-models

I have a field called `status`.
I want to pluralize status, so I write

```
def get_status_display(self):
    return dict(STATUS_CHOICES).get(self.status) + 's'
```

In template I write `{{ object.get_status_display }}`
But this function is not invoked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `get_FOO_display()` methods are added to the class at runtime, after the class definition, so you can't override them. Why don't you simply add the `s` in `STATUS_CHOICES` directly?

Comment: [Unanswered duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40543208/1324033)

Comment: That was somewhat simplified example. Logic there is a bit harder. When I create instance manually status can have special option, but in a form this option is empty. How can I show display value for special option?

Comment: Sounds like something you should be doing in the form, but you should ask about that instead. [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)